# What is the error “dsfont.sty” in beamer?

Tags: errors, packages

I am using beamer and I am getting error "dsfont.sty". I do not know how to solve that. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Kile. I appreciate your assistance in this regard.

Comment: `dsfont.sty` isn't an error. It might be part of an error, like "Package not found" but you haven't given nearly enough information to help you. Can you edit your question to show a 1 frame document that reproduces the error? And show the the entire error line from your log.

Comment: Please don't post partial screen shots of code (or screen shots of code at all). We need to see the code that produced the error, preferably after you remove everything else that isn't needed to reproduce the error. And you still haven't shown the full error line from the log file. But guessing from what you have shown, try adding `\usepackage{dsfont}` to your preamble.